# Bigger buffer size for MusicPlayer output

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

In an app for iOS 8 in Swift, I create and store MIDI data.
The data is then passed to a MidiPlayer which, in a properly set AUGraph, plays back the MIDI.
While this works well in the emulator, sometimes the audio is crackling on my iPhone 4s. As this happens when the generated MIDI contains *lots* of fast notes, I guess that the iPhone's CPU is simply not fast enough.
I think that with a bigger buffer size, things would be better.
How can I set up this bigger buffer?
Should I address the RemoteIO in the AUGraph telling it to use a bigger buffer?
I tried the following before initializing the graph:

```
var myAudioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
println("IOBufferDuration : \(myAudioSession.IOBufferDuration)")

var theError:NSError?
myAudioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.46, error: &theError)
if (theError != nil) {
    println("Error: \(theError!.localizedDescription)")
}
println("New IOBufferDuration : \(myAudioSession.IOBufferDuration)")

myAudioSession.setActive(true, error: &theError)
if (theError != nil) {
    println("Error: \(theError!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

but even if I don't get errors, my code has no influence on the buffer size, which is seemingly chosen by the system at startup. Moreover, the audio goes silent...

Thanks!